# gRPC server to client streaming does not work

Tags: c#, .net, grpc

Hi i am trying to establish bidirectional communication using gRPC. Client to server communication works fine but on the other hand server to client streaming does not work.

Here is my .proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "GrpcService";

import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";

package Server;

service ApplicationService
{
  rpc SendText (TextMessage) returns (google.protobuf.Empty);
  rpc SubscribeText (google.protobuf.Empty) returns (stream OnTextChangedEventArgs);
}

message TextMessage
{
  string Text = 1;
}

message OnTextChangedEventArgs
{
    string Text = 1;
}
```

Here is ServerApplicationService.cs file:

```
namespace GrpcService.Services
{
    public class ServerApplicationService : ApplicationService.ApplicationServiceBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ServerApplicationService> logger;
        private Text text;

        public ServerApplicationService(ILogger<ServerApplicationService> logger, Text text)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
            this.text = text;
        }

        public override Task<Empty> SendText(TextMessage request, ServerCallContext context)
        {
            this.logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, nameof(SendText));
            this.text.Value = request.Text;

            return Task.FromResult(new Empty());
        }

        public override Task SubscribeText(Empty request, IServerStreamWriter<OnTextChangedEventArgs> responseStream, ServerCallContext context)
        {
            this.text.ValueChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                this.logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, nameof(SubscribeText));
                responseStream.WriteAsync(new OnTextChangedEventArgs()
                {
                    Text = this.text.Value
                });
            };

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

And the last one is Client.cs:

```
namespace GrpcClient
{
    public class TextChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string Text { get; }

        public TextChangedEventArgs(string text)
        {
            this.Text = text;
        }
    }

    class GrpcCallbacks
    {
        private bool isRunning;
        private ApplicationService.ApplicationServiceClient client;

        public event EventHandler<TextChangedEventArgs> TextChanged;

        public GrpcCallbacks(ApplicationService.ApplicationServiceClient client)
        {
            this.client = client;
        }

        public void RunCallbacks()
        {
            if (this.isRunning)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }

            this.isRunning = true;
            Task.Run(this.RunCallbacksInternal);
        }

        private async Task RunCallbacksInternal()
        {
            using (AsyncServerStreamingCall<OnTextChangedEventArgs> response = this.client.SubscribeText(new Empty()))
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Task timer = Task.Delay(10);

                    while (await response.ResponseStream.MoveNext())
                    {
                        OnTextChangedEventArgs args = response.ResponseStream.Current;
                        this.TextChanged?.Invoke(this, new TextChangedEventArgs(args.Text));
                    }
                    await timer;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:7050");
            var client = new ApplicationService.ApplicationServiceClient(channel);
            var callbacks = new GrpcCallbacks(client);

            callbacks.TextChanged += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine(args.Text);
            callbacks.RunCallbacks();
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            client.SendText(new TextMessage { Text = "a" });
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

In the client side in method `RunCallbacksInternal` line `await response.ResponseStream.MoveNext()` always returns false and `response.ResponseStream.Current` is always null so no data is incomming into buffer from server, but the event on the server side `ValueChanged` is fired so the `responseStream.WriteAsync(new OnTextChangedEventArgs() { Text = this.text.Value });` is called.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two problems that I can see server-side (I haven't looked client-side); the first is that you *don't await `WriteAsync`*, the second is that you return `Task.Completed` from `SubscribeText` - but that means "I'm done, end of stream". The idea here is that you perform some number of `await ... WriteAsync` calls *before* indicating that you're done, perhaps using `Channel<T>` or similar as an async buffer.

Comment: So I tried to make the subscribed handler `async` and awaited the `WriteAsync` method. Now I get InvalidOperationException with message 'Can't write the message because the request is complete.'. Now I know why the `WriteAsync` did't work.

Comment: I figure it out. You cannot create handlers inside the overriden rpc method and user the `IServerStreamWriter<SubscribeResponse>` outside of this method (in my case it is inside subscribed handler. This is responsible for throwing InvalidOperationException. I have created another solution and now everything works as expected. Thank you for your help.